# Build a standalone bash

Tags: bash, compiling, static-linking

I would like to build standalone bash binaries, which would hopefully work on a good portion of the linux distributions out there. Complete coverage is definitely not a goal. How would I approach this? Best-effort suggestions welcome.
I understand that each distribution has e.g. unique readline implementations. If it is feasible, I would like to statically link a fixed version and ship it with the standalone bash on e.g. an usb stick.

Hope someone can help me with that :) cheers

Comment: So, which part are you having trouble with? Have you got bash to build yet? Are you having problems statically linking readline?

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and then learn [how to ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This'll make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Just running the bash from centos on debian works for me -- no need to build anything ;-) `bash` come with its own readline, doesn't use the library from the system (just run `ldd bash` if you don't believe me). @muru building static binaries against glibc is only possible as long as they don't use any name resolution functions -- because glibc implements that by loading shared objects with `dlopen`. `bash` has to use name resolution for the `/dev/tcp/host/port` hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the [bash-static](https://packages.debian.org/stable/bash-static) package from Debian and extract the executable.

```
ar p bash-static_*.deb data.tar.xz | tar -xJ ./bin/bash-static
```

If you want to see how it's done, look in the sources. The build instructions are in `debian/rules`. There's a lot of expansion going on, so run it:

```
debian/rules static-build
```

I think all you need is this (but I haven't tried):

```
./configure --enable-static-link
make
```

The question is why you'd want to do that. Virtually all distributions already have bash installed as `/bin/bash`, and it isn't optional. It would be more useful with zsh which in most distributions is available, but not installed by default. For zsh, you need (again, untried):

```
./configure --enable-ldflags=-static --disable-dynamic --disable-dynamic-nss
make
```

Comment: You may want to get the i386 one so it works on both x86 and x86_64.

Comment: For reference, Busybox doesn't ship with bash. I'm right now working on a setup where I need to use Busybox, but I have a bash script to run :(